# Getting key value of WP_Term object in wordpress

Tags: php, categories

How I can get from php on wordpress to a value of WP_Term object. I am using the next code to get the object:

```
$queried_object = get_the_category( get_queried_object_id());
```

But this return an Array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 12
            [name] => Argentina
            ...
        )

)
```

How I can get only the value for [name] key in this object from php in wordpress?

Answer (score 6):

It returns an array because Posts can have multiple categories. You just need to get the item from the array whose name you want, (`$queried_object[0]` for the first one), then get the value out  of that the same way you would any PHP object:

```
$name = $queried_object[0]->name;
```

You should probably include some checks to make sure the post has a category before attempting to use the array or object like this:

```
$categories = get_the_category( get_queried_object_id() );

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $category = $categories[0];
    $name = $category->name;
}
```